# Setting the correct PATH for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, path

I recently changed my path so I could follow along in the Head First Java book and I had Eclipse before. Now when I try to get onto Eclipse again it won't open because it says it can't find a JRE or JDK to use in my directory. I have moved the JDK file around. I have jdk1.8.0_60 downloaded. So how can I get Eclipse to open again?

Comment: Try editing the `eclipse.ini` file (In `~/eclipse/java-mars/eclipse` for me; would probably be in `C:\Program Files` somewhere for windows.) and changing the line after '-vm' to your actual jdk path.

Comment: Also, change your PATH to include the jdk directory.

Comment: Also check if you have installed the x32 or x64 version of Java and certify the same for eclipse that you have previously downloaded.

Comment: I've tried changing my Path to ThisPC\Desktop\eclipse\jdk1.8.0_60\bin and it's not working. I even tried putting the jdk1.8.0_60 file in the eclipse file itself and that's not working either...

Comment: Moving your JDK file or directory will just mess things up even more; it's an installed program and should be placed where it was originally installed. Eclipse doesn't just look at `PATH`. Also, you shouldn't be **changing** your `PATH`, you should be _adding_ to it. You shouldn't also change `PATH` to the bin folder, just the default installation directory itself.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

[Like Abob said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35881879/3357935):

> Eclipse doesn't consult the `JAVA_HOME` variable

You should specify where Eclipse should find your JDK in the file `eclipse.ini`. Specifically, the following parameter (note that it is 2 separate lines in the ini file):

```
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.8\bin\javaw.exe
```

or wherever your javaw.exe happens to be.

**Note:** *The format of the `ini` file is very particular; make sure to consult https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini to ensure you get it exactly right.*

Comment: It's worth noting this can be used to run Eclipse off a USB drive using [Java Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable). Simply use a relative path such as `\PortableApps\Programs\CommonFiles\Java\bin`

Comment: The note was very helpful - the line only worked for me once I moved it above the -vmargs

Comment: Also make sure that correct java version is mapped. Like win32 has jdk_32 and 64 one has that one. Helpful.

Comment: I can't find -vm in my eclipse.ini file. just -vmargs. What do I do?

Comment: @madladzen : You can just add it then. -vmargs  supplies arguments, -vm points to the jvm that eclipse should use. Take a look at the linked wiki, it explains everything pretty well

Answer (score 31):

Eclipse folder has an initialization file which is used by eclipse on launch/Double click it is named as eclipse.ini. Add the following lines in eclipse.ini file. Where the vm defines the path of J**VM** with which we want eclipse to use.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8\bin\javaw.exe
```

Make sure you have add the above lines separately and above the following line

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
```

Comment: For Spring Tool Suite [3.8.3.RELEASE-e4.6.2]
"
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin\javaw.exe "

add the above lines separately and before the following line
"
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 "

Answer (score 15):

Go to `System Properties > Advanced > Enviroment Variables` and look under `System variables`

### First, create/set your `JAVA_HOME` variable

Even though Eclipse doesn't consult the `JAVA_HOME` variable, it's still a good idea to set it. See [How do I run Eclipse?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F) for more information.

If you have not created and/or do not see `JAVA_HOME` under the list of `System variables`, do the following:

1. Click `New...` at the very bottom
2. For `Variable name`, type `JAVA_HOME` **exactly**
3. For `Variable value`, this could be different depending on what bits your computer and java are.

   - If both your **computer and java are *64-bit***, type `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60`
   - If both your **computer and java are *32-bit***, type `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60`
   - If your **computer is *64-bit***, but your **java is *32-bit***, type `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60`

If you have created and/or do see `JAVA_HOME`, do the following:

1. Click on the row under `System variables` that you see `JAVA_HOME` in
2. Click `Edit...` at the very bottom
3. For `Variable value`, change it to what was stated in #3 above based on java's and your computer's bits. To repeat:

   - If both your **computer and java are *64-bit***, change it to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60`
   - If both your **computer and java are *32-bit***, change it to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60`
   - If your **computer is *64-bit***, but your **java is *32-bit***, change it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60`

### Next, add to your `PATH` variable

1. Click on the row under `System variables` with `PATH` in it
2. Click `Edit...` at the very bottom
3. If you have a **newer version** of windows:

   - Click `New`
   - Type in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60` ***OR*** `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60` depending on the bits of your computer and java (see above ^).
   - Press `Enter` and Click `New` again.
   - Type in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre` ***OR*** `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre` depending on the bits of your computer and java (see above again ^).
   - Press `Enter` and press `OK` on all of the related windows
4. If you have an **older version** of windows

   - In the `Variable value` textbox (or something similar) drag the cursor all the way to the very end
   - Add a semicolon (`;`) if there isn't one already
   - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60` ***OR*** `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60`
   - Add another semicolon (`;`)
   - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre` ***OR*** `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre`

### Changing `eclipse.ini`

1. Find your `eclipse.ini` file and copy-paste it in the same directory (should be named `eclipse(1).ini`)
2. Rename `eclipse.ini` to `eclipse.ini.old` just in case something goes wrong
3. Rename `eclipse(1).ini` to `eclipse.ini`
4. Open your newly-renamed `eclipse.ini` and replace all of it with this:

   ```
   -startup
   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
   --launcher.library
   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
   -product
   org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
   --launcher.defaultAction
   openFile
   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
   256M
   -showsplash
   org.eclipse.platform
   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
   256m
   --launcher.defaultAction
   openFile
   -vm
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javaw.exe
   -vmargs
   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
   -Xms40m
   -Xmx1024m
   ```

`XXMaxPermSize` may be deprecated, so it might not work. ***If eclipse still does not launch, do the following:***

1. Delete the newer `eclipse.ini`
2. Rename `eclipse.ini.old` to `eclipse.ini`
3. Open command prompt
4. type in `eclipse -vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javaw.exe`

### If the problem remains

Try updating your eclipse and java to the latest version. 8u60 (`1.8.0_60`) is not the latest version of java. Sometimes, the latest version of java doesn't work with older versions of eclipse and vice versa. Otherwise, leave a comment if you're still having problems. You could also try a fresh reinstallation of Java.

Comment: It's still not working. I re-downloaded eclipse and put it all in the eclipse2 folder on my desktop. I don't know why I am still getting an error when I try to open Eclipse. The error is saying that no virtual machine was located when looking in this location: **C:Users\Ty\Desktop\eclipse2\jre\bin\javaw.exe**

Comment: If it can't find the JVM in the eclipse directory, try moving it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin` or `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin` depending on bits (the default directory; See [Finding the JVM](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM)) and then following the new section i posted in my answer. If that doesn't work, remove all java installations and install the latest version from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comment: All of this stuff about JAVA_HOME and PATH is meaningless to running Eclipse. And the advice about replacing the *entire* contents of eclipse.ini is VERY BAD advice - different packages of Eclipse and different versions will have different contents in eclipse.ini, so blindly replacing them will likely break things. All that's necessary is to make sure there is a `-vm` parameter and valid value, as described at https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Answer (score 2):

I am using Windows 8.1 environment. I had the same problem while running my first java program after installing Eclipse recently. 
I had installed java on d drive at d:\java.
But Eclipse was looking at the default installation c:\programfiles\java.
I did the following:

1. Modified my eclipse.ini file and added the following after open:

   ```
   -vm
   d:\java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin
   ```
2. While creating the java program I have to unselect default build path and then select d:\java.

After this, the program ran well and got the hello world to work.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this problem by adding or changing variables in environment variables.
Go to Win7 -> My Computer - > Properties - > Advanced system settings -> environment Variables

1. If there is no variable JAVA_HOME, add it with value of variable, with route to folder where your JDK installed, for examle C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2
2. If there is no variable PATH or it have another value, change the value of variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin or add variable PATH  with this value

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

There are working combinations of OS, JDK and Eclipse bitness. In my case, I was using a 64-bit JDK with a 32-bit Eclipse on a 64-bit OS. After downgrading the JDK to 32-bit, Eclipse started working.

Kindly use one of the following combinations.

32-bit OS, 32-bit JDK, 32-bit Eclipse (32-bit only)

64-bit OS, 32-bit JDK, 32-bit Eclipse

64-bit OS, 64-bit JDK, 64-bit Eclipse (64-bit only)

Answer (score 0):

For me none worked. I compared my existing `eclipse.ini` with a new one and started removing options and testing if eclipse worked.

The only option that prevented eclipse from starting was `-XX:+UseParallelGC`, so I removed it and voilá!