# how to install eclipse neo IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to install the eclipse neo in the system. I have already latest version of java 1.8 but getting the error. I have uploaded the error image for your reference.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzhbp.png)

Comment: Can you start eclipse with `-consoleLog` parameter?

Comment: this question may be helpful [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394822/setting-up-eclipse-with-jre-path]

Comment: this is also [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881210/setting-the-correct-path-for-eclipse]

Comment: You have a 64 bit Eclipse and a 32 bit Java. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem and I solved it.

The cause of the problem is the java version you have. I mean if you have *eclipse 32* you should use *java 32* and if you have *eclipse 64* you should use *java 64*.