# Maven build is successful but missing a dependency. JDWP exit error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-neon, javapoet

[SOLVED] Sigh, just had to Project > Clean > Build. Using Run As > Maven build... was not having it.

I'm trying to use JavaPoet to build an enum based off annotations I've created, but I'm having trouble adding the Maven dependency. I resolve log4j2, H2, and Reflections dependencies successfully, but cannot resolve JavaPoet.

I'm having trouble finding any answers on what this `FATAL ERROR` is, any help is appreciated. I'm using Eclipse Neon.3, I don't have much RAM on my laptop -- only 4GB. Here is my Maven build output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building My Project 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ MainClass ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\dev\git\MainClass\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MainClass---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ MainClass
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 90 source files to C:\dev\git\MainClass\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.252 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-08T09:54:56-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/169M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP on getting class status, jvmtiError=JVMTI_ERROR_WRONG_PHASE(112)
JDWP exit error JVMTI_ERROR_WRONG_PHASE(112): on getting class status [util.c:1285]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also getting the same error in Eclipse IDE whenever I do the run maven goal clean install.

Build was successful but then displays below error.

JDWP exit error JVMTI_ERROR_WRONG_PHASE(112): on getting class status [util.c:1285]

But was surprised to see that the same maven goal was running perfectly outside eclipse in a command prompt.

To analyse further, in eclipse I opened the terminal window and ran below commands to know java compiler/vm versions

```
javac -version
java -version
```

and found that both was pointing to slight different versions.

**Adding following lines in eclipse.ini file solved the issue.**

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe
```

Make sure you have add the above lines separately and above the following line

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
```

Refer this link for [Setting the correct PATH for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881210/setting-the-correct-path-for-eclipse) and now

```
C:\Users\tarun.kumar2>java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode)

C:\Users\tarun.kumar2>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_91
```

I hope this helps you.