# Failed to create Java Virtual Machine after updating. :(

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've got this message (Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine) after updating some installed plugins.

I have no idea that how can i fix it ?
Please help me guys :(

I'm using eclipse Oxygen.(upgraded few weeks ago)
beneath lines are my eclipse.ini

```html
1-startup
  2 ../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
  3 --launcher.library
  4 ../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.550.    v20170928-1359
  5 -product
  6 org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
  7 -showsplash
  8 org.eclipse.epp.package.common
  9 --launcher.defaultAction
 10 openFile
 11 --launcher.defaultAction
 12 openFile
 13 --launcher.appendVmargs
 14 -vmargs
 15 -javaagent:../Eclipse/lombok.jar
 16 -javaagent:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/com.zeroturnar    ound.eclipse.optimizer.plugin_1.0.11/agent/eclipse-optimizer-agent.jar
 17 -server
 18 -XX:PermSize=256m
 19 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
 20 -XX:+UseParallelGC
 21 -Xverify:none
 22 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
 23 -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
 24 -XX:+UseG1GC
 25 -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
 26 --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
 27 -XstartOnFirstThread
 28 -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
 29 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
 30 -Xms512m
 31 -Xmx3072m
 32 --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
 33 -Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
 34 -XstartOnFirstThread
 35 -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

Comment: do you get the error when starting Eclipse? Do you get a stack trace to share?

Comment: That looks like an old eclipse.ini, e.g. `-XX:PermSize=256m` and `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8` don't work well together (PermGen doesn't exist in Java 8 anymore). Try with a fresh/default eclipse.ini.

Comment: my eclipse is perfectly new...
=========
Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
Build id: 20171005-1200
==========
maybe version caused this problem

Comment: how can i get fresh or default eclipse.ini ?

Answer (score 0):

This might come when the java upgrade happens in the machine. verify eclipse.ini file and set 
-vmargs 
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 (which is the latest version)

Comment: 9 is the latest version.

Comment: actually i solved this problem.. but another problem came out immediately.
anyway
A) i commented -vmargs line in eclipse.ini then it worked.
B) another problem is i can't use lombok.jar, lombok annotations are not working out..

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps, It may help you.

[image]i.stack.imgur.com/PtDpw.png

Also visit: [Setting the correct PATH for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881210/setting-the-correct-path-for-eclipse) to update **eclipse.ini**

Comment: java SE8 1.8.0_131 has set as default.

Answer (score 0):

first, i commented -vmargs line of eclipse.ini

then i faced problem that lombok doesn't work for eclipse Oxygen.1A

you will need to launch eclipse on the command line on Terminal..ETC.

```html
./eclipse -vmargs -javaagent:../Eclipse/lombok.jar
```

Then you can check installed lombok from 'About Eclipse' 
but i don't know how can i activate lombok as eclipse icon launching.