# Eclipse not opening but Java path are set properly

Tags: java, eclipse

If I try to open Eclipse, it was loading for some time and it's not opening so I have checked the metadata log it's showing the error as below:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.ui 4 0 2018-12-14 11:35:24.267
!MESSAGE Monitor UI stop failed
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.monitor.ui.ActivityContextManager.stop(ActivityContextManager.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.monitor.ui.MonitorUiPlugin.stop(MonitorUiPlugin.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1206)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.decFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.shutdown(StartLevelManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.suspend(InternalSystemBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.shutdown(Framework.java:692)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.close(Framework.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.shutdown(EclipseStarter.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881210/setting-the-correct-path-for-eclipse

Comment: What version of Eclipse? This looks like bug [392346](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392346) which was fixed 5 years ago.

Comment: I have uninstalled and installed again now it's working fine. Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Juno Service Release 2

Comment: Eclipse Juno is pretty old, please upgrade. The current version is 2018-09 and next week 2018-12 will be released.