# How to build a java path in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I just want to know how do I see/restore my java project so that I can right click on it. Because I need to make a java path into it. I think I accidentally removed it on my sidebar, all I can see in my sidebar is the package and the main method java. Please help me.

[My issue:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNfnD.png)

It should show the java project name on my sidebar so that I can right click on it.

Comment: I do not clearly understand your issue here.
You want to import a project into eclipse or want to setting eclipse's java path.
For setting java path, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881210/setting-the-correct-path-for-eclipse

Comment: How do I send an image so you can understand?

Comment: if you are using Windows, you can use Snipping Tool or press Windows + Shift + S to take picture, then Ctrl + V into your post above.

Comment: I edited it, take a look at it.

Comment: is it just a new blank project ?

Comment: if you are new to Java, you need to know that JDK need to be installed before you can build and run java code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you can right click on the main package and click import the project. Try it and let us know.